# How to Use Blurhash in flutter App or Flutter Project

Tags: flutter

```
CachedNetworkImage(
   imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
   placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
// i want to use Blurhash on placeholder 
   errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```

https://pub.dev/packages/blurhash

i didn't found Any single Tutorial on it..
I Need Help

Comment: you can use `FutureBuilder` that way blurhash widget will load only after completion of future, given you add state handling in builder. Depending on use case you might want to load the placeholder( blurhash of image) first then load your screen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can `await` `BlurHash` image in `main()` and then use in `CachedNetworkImage` 
code snippet

```
Uint8List imageDataBytes;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  imageDataBytes =
      await BlurHash.decode("LBAdAqof00WCqZj[PDay0.WB}pof", 32, 32);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
...
 CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150',
              placeholder: (BuildContext context, String url) =>
                  Image.memory(imageDataBytes, width: 256, fit: BoxFit.cover),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
```

working demo snapshot

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:blurhash/blurhash.dart';

Uint8List imageDataBytes;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  imageDataBytes =
      await BlurHash.decode("LBAdAqof00WCqZj[PDay0.WB}pof", 32, 32);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150',
              placeholder: (BuildContext context, String url) =>
                  Image.memory(imageDataBytes, width: 256, fit: BoxFit.cover),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution... **But what if** I don't want to add imageDataBytes =
      await BlurHash.decode("LBAdAqof00WCqZj[PDay0.WB}pof", 32, 32); in void main() because i want to add hashcode into different screen

Comment: add in main() is only to make sure image is ready when use it. you can use in different screen just make sure image is ready before use it.

Comment: i try to add blurhash **(imageDataBytes =
      await BlurHash.decode("LBAdAqof00WCqZj[PDay0.WB}pof", 32, 32) ** into initstate() but it's giving an Error about async then I create a different function and add into init() but before loading image showing Red Screen error for microsecond

Comment: that's the main reason I put it in main(). when you put code in  initstate() ,because await means need time. when build is start, you are still await image, and image is not still not ready.

Comment: is there any other way around??

Comment: placeholder need exist before network image, if not use as placeholder, you can check imageDataBytes == null and return Text("not exist") or circularprogressindicator